# Using ant <propertyregex>, how can I capture the /etc/shadow record for a user?

Tags: regex, linux, ant, shadow

From ant, we want to **extract a line from an old /etc/shadow file, capturing the line for a specific user name, such as "manager"**.  This is part of a backup/restore operation.  What we used previously was not specific enough, so it would match users like "mymanager", so we tried to tighten it down by **anchoring the start of the string** to beginning of the line (typically "^").  *This definitely did not work as we expected.*

**How can we anchor so that we get an exact match for a username? -- answered below.**

First attempt, which gave the wrong result if we had a user of "mymanager" in the /etc/shadow file copy:

```
<loadfile property="oldPasswords" srcFile="${backup.dir}/shadow"/>
<propertyregex property="manager.backup" input="${oldPasswords}"
    regexp="(manager\:.*)" select="\1" casesensitive="true" />
```

Second attempt, which failed because "^" is not interpreted in the normal regular expression way by default:

```
<loadfile property="oldPasswords" srcFile="${backup.dir}/shadow"/>
<propertyregex property="manager.backup" input="${oldPasswords}"
    regexp="^(manager\:.*)" select="\1" casesensitive="true" />
```

Kobi suggested adding -> flags="m" <- which sounded good but ant reported that the flags option is not supported by propertyregex.

**The final, successful, approach required inserting "(?m)" at the beginning of the regexp:** That was the essential change.

```
<propertyregex property="manager.backup" input="${oldPasswords}"
    regexp="(?m)^manager:.*$" select="\0" casesensitive="true" />
```

The regexp with propertyregex appears to follow the rules in this documentation of regular expressions in Java (search for "multiline" for example): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Check the above document if you have similar questions about how to make **propertyregex** and **regexp** *do what you want them to do*!

THANKS! Solved.

Alan Carwile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the m(ultiline) flag is what you want to use and will give the start-of-line anchor the right behavior. It's possible to change flags within the regular expression with the syntax `(?<flagstoturnon>-<flagstoturnoff>)`. So in your case, adding `(?m)` to the start of the regular expression (before the caret) should work.

Comment: Thanks Geoff and thanks Kobi.  Kobi was right about the multiline mode.  The syntax given by Geoff solves the issue.  I changed to now use:   regexp="(?m)^manager:.*$"  and it works exactly as needed.  I'll add a bit more info at the bottom of my original question (above) to help anyone else who comes along with a similar issue.  THANKS!